# Bootstrap 4 - Scrollspy not working

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have followed the documentation on how to use Scrollspy in BS4, but it is not working, so how do I solve it?

My body has `posistion: relative`

This is my body tag:

```
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar">
```

And this is the HTML for the navbar:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded">
    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="container">

        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
            <img src="/images/logo_placeholder.jpg" width="90" height="45" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="">
            Jalinen
        </a>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#home">Home </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Nieuws</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Diensten</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Calamiteiten</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Gallerij</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Why is it not working?

Note:

Nothing works atm.

The navbar doesn't even stick to the top of the page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you're using `fixed-top` to attach the navbar to the top,

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md fixed-top navbar-light bg-faded">
  ..
</nav>
```

and the body tag:

`<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#navbar1" data-offset="70">`

[Bootstrap 4 Scrollspy Demo](http://www.codeply.com/go/7CDRomtM0D)

***EDIT:*** 
`navbar-toggleable-md` has changed to `navbar-expand-lg` in **Bootstrap 4.0.0**

Comment: Yes, that fixed it. I already figuered it out myself, but will still accept this answer because it is the answer to my problem.

Comment: Bootstrap 4 scrollspy data-foofset not working with smooth scroll event. It work normally but solution not perfect.

Comment: You downvoted this because it doesn't work with your custom smooth scroll event?? This answer works as described in the question above which has nothing to do with smooth scrolling.

Answer (score 2):

You content sections must have unique ID (#about) which is connected to an anchor in the navigation. (Your #home ID is valid only)

Correct:

```
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#home">Home </a>
            </li>
```

Wrong:

```
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Nieuws</a>
            </li>
```

Comment: Yes, I know. But the navbar won't even stick to the top of my page in the first place. And after removing those that where wrong, it didn't work either

Answer (score 0):

My BS4 sticky-top navbar started scrolling up and disappeared when scrolling down.
Removed the CSS below I added for some purpose and worked again.

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap 3.3.7 puts the `active` class on the `li` element, and bootstrap 4 puts the `active` class on the `a` tag.  Make sure to set styles accordingly.
For a sticky navbar, assign the class `.fixed-top` to the navbar.

Answer (score 0):

Class active `.active` is the solution.
Just add this to your css styles:

```
.nav-link.active {
background-color: white; 
color: #f4511e;           
}
```

That `.active` makes the difference.
Change `background-color` and `color` at your will.

Also it is important to set:

```
body {position: relative}
```